# What is the difference between subfigure and subcaptionbox both from package subcaption?

Tags: graphics, floats, captions, subfloats, subcaption

I was recently searching for a way to place subfigures into one overall figure. As I found out, today we should make use of the [subcaption package](https://ctan.org/pkg/subcaption?lang=de) rather than usig subfig or something else.

However, as googling I found two approaches which seems for me to do the same. For this here is my complete MWE:

```
 \documentclass[]{article}
 \usepackage{mwe}
 \usepackage{subcaption}
 \begin{document}
 \blindtext


 %%%SUBCAPTIONBOX->
 \begin{figure}[h!]
 \centering
 \subcaptionbox{$n = 10$ steps\label{cw_10}}{%
 \includegraphics[width=.48\linewidth]{example-image-a}%
 }\hfill
 \subcaptionbox{$n = 25$ steps\label{cw_25}}{%
 \includegraphics[width=.48\linewidth]{example-image-a}%
 }
 \caption{A figure with two subfigures using SUBCAPTION}
 \label{TS}
 \end{figure}
 %%%<-SUBCAPTIONBOX

 %%%SUBFIGURE->
 \begin{figure}[h!]
 \begin{subfigure}[b]{.45\linewidth}
 \centering
 \includegraphics[width=1\linewidth]{example-image-a}%
 \caption{$n = 10$ steps}
 \label{cw_10}
 \end{subfigure}%
 \hfill
 \begin{subfigure}[b]{.45\linewidth}
 \centering
 \includegraphics[width=1\linewidth]{example-image-a}%
 \subcaption{$n = 25$ steps}
 \label{cw_25}
 \end{subfigure}
 \caption{A figure with two subfigures using SUBFIGURE}
 \label{TS}
 \end{figure}
 %%%<-SUBFIGURE
 \blindtext

 \end{document}
```

First, I am using a method with subcaptionbox, then with subfigure-environment. Which one is better or is some Approach 'wrong'?

My Code result in this Picture, I did not see any difference:

[image]

Comment: I took the liberty to edit the title of your question. I hope this reflects the contents of your actual question a bit better.

Comment: The `subcaption` manual contains the following statement: "A different way of setting sub-figures is offered by the `\subcaptionbox` command [...]" So I'd say both methods can be used equally. A difference between the two however is, that with `subfigure` you secify two widths, the width of the `subfigure` and the width of the image, while `subcaptionbox` only needs the width of the image.

Comment: Off topic, Since \subcaption in a figure is the same as \caption in a subfigure, shouldn't \subcaption in a subfigure produce a subsubcaption?

Answer (score 6):

- The `\subcaptionbox` is based on `\parbox` (and therefore inherits its optional argument "inner-pos") while `subfigure` is based on the `minipage` environment (which offers a different set of optional arguments).
- If no width is given, the `\subcaptionbox` is as wide as its contents. (When using `subfigure` a width has always to be given explicitly since it's a mandatory argument there.)
- When using `\subcaptionbox` the caption will be placed above or below its contents, depending on the `position=` option. When using `subfigure` the caption will be placed where `\caption` is.
- When using `\subcaptionbox` the baseline of the resulting `\parbox` will be identical with the baseline of the 1st caption line. When using `subfigure` the baseline is dependent on the content (and the optional alignment parameter "outer-pos" which isn't available for `\subcaptionbox`).